# All multiplicative sets of the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers

I'm currently looking for all the subsets $ S$ of $ \mathbb{Z}$ which are closed under integer multiplication. Such sets are called multiplicative. My first idea was that all of those subsets were of the form $n\mathbb{Z}$  but then I realized that $3^2\equiv_6 3 $ so $6\mathbb{Z}+3$ is also multiplicative. This led me to think that the multiplicative subsets of $\mathbb{Z} $ were of the form $ (n\mathbb{Z})+r$ where $ r$ is idempotent modulo $ n$. But then I realized that the complement of  $p\mathbb{Z} $  (here $ p$ is a prime like always) is also multiplicative. Ok, after thinking a while I came to the conclusion that these are all the multiplicative subsets of the integers but I'm not absolutley sure nor know how to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Also $\{2n\mid n\ge 0\}$ is closed under multiplication, but different from $2\Bbb{Z}$. Isn't [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1835940/multiplicatively-closed-subsets-of-z) the same one?

Comment: You are right, we must add $ n\mathbb{N}+r$ where $ r$ is idempotent modulo $n $.

Comment: Closed under multiplication is different from [multiplicatively closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicatively_closed_set), where we require in addition that $1\in S$.

Comment: Natalio, you must also add the set of integers $S$, which can be represented as the sum of two squares, and many more things. So again, as in the duplicate, I am not sure whether or not a classification is possible.

Comment: Also family of these sets is closed for intersection and product.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you very much, probably a clasifiacation is not posible.